# Trying to get control of spam?

Tags: spam

Hopefully this question is deemed acceptable for this area of stackexchange. if not let me know what other site to use.

Anyways i'm seeking advice on how you try to eliminate spam in your daily lives. What i've done up to this point is just a total pain and i'm about to give up. I own my own domain. I essential have group email addresses. For example i have one email address for orders, one for forums, one for things that require my email that i never want to hear from, ect... Why is this such a pain? Well i use office 365 and you have to pay for each email address (so i only have 1). You can create forward email addresses so forward1@example.com will get redirected to mymainemail@example.com but you can email from the forwarded addresses. So i can't send an email from forward1@example.com which has caused issues.

Also say if you used forward1@example.com for all your orders and you have 50 sites you order from....not so easy to change is it? I will never be able to eliminate all but one account because you need say a google account if you use their services and a live.com account if you microsoft service but at least it would greatly diminish the headache i have now? Would you just forget about trying to use multiple email addresses and rely on strong spam protection? To be honest with you no one has my main email address...so at this point what good is it :).

We know no matter how careful you are eventually spam bots will get ahold of your address somehow (in someone elses address book or because of weak security on a site).

Comment: The fact that you choose to use office 365 and that decides that you should pay per e-mail account is irrelevant from a security standpoint, but I think the rest of the question is acceptable.
Instead of creating many e-mail addresses, have you looked into [sub-addressing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Address_tags) as described in [rfc5233](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5233)

Comment: @user2813274 well i'm trying to explain context here. If one was using a cheapo pop email solution then i might be able to create/destroy email addresses on the fly which might make a "slight" difference but in the overall scheme of things your right won't make that much of a difference.

Comment: I don't particularly see the benefit of using your own domain e-mail for every single forum that you sign up for as opposed to a disposable one.. can you confirm/deny if the office 365 email works the same ways as outlook with the + character?

Comment: @user2813274 the concept is to use say forward1@example.com for forums. As soon as you start to receive spam. You change your email to forward2@example.com and either delete forward1@example.com or automatically delete it with a filter emails to that address in a filter. I think what "+" your referring to is 4 gmail. It works similar.

Comment: According to the [wiki link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Address_tags) the + is by no means specific to g-mail, it actually says that outlook has it as well, which leads me to believe that office 365 is likely to have it, and I am asking for confirmation of that - and if so, why not use it for each account individually?

Answer (score 2):

I use a different mail for every service, like facebook@mydomain.com, google@mydomain.com etc. This way I can see who sells my data or gets hacked (poor adobe@mydomain.com; )). Also I don't have to change 50 profiles after one incident but only one.

To adress your problem with Office360: I made a catch-all adress on my domain, where all mails arrive, so I only have to get mails from one inbox. If I see too many spam from one adress I simply block it.

The bigger problem is sending mails. Some Programms offer to enter any sender-address you like, but I know Outlook doesn't. Here I personally use a selfhosted webmailer where I can send from what address I like. It may not be the simplest solution but it works great for me.

For some important comunication it is also possible to create a temporary account while it lasts and delete it afterwards. I still get the mails through my catch-all address but have only one to manage.

I use this system for many years now and I have to say I am very satisfied with it. Not only I get nearly no spam but I also like the fact that I can identify which services I can trust and which not.